# Docker compose can't find Python main

Tags: python, docker

Trying to learn how to use Docker with a database by dockerising my existing project, but `Docker compose up` returns the following:

`python: can't open file '/src/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I can build the image and access the `main.py` quite easily, just not able to access the db in the container yet. I would expect to get the same problem with docker compose up

```
//build image
$ docker build --tag cyber-test --progress=plain .

... //get all the logs
$ docker run --rm -it cyber-test /bin/bash
root@90f3624529af:/#
root@90f3624529af:/# ls
Dockerfile  bin   data  dev                 etc   lib    media  opt   root  sbin  srv  tmp  var
README.md   boot  db    docker-compose.yml  home  lib64  mnt    proc  run   src   sys  usr  venv
root@90f3624529af:/#
root@90f3624529af:/# python src/main.py
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused //I would expect to get at least this far
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /
COPY . .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r src/requirements.txt
RUN ls && pwd
CMD ["python", "src/main.py"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: cyber-image
    stdin_open: true

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - cyber-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_SCHEMA: postgres

volumes:
  cyber-data:
    driver: local
```

project structure:

[image]

What have I missed?

Comment: Move the Dockerfile in the `src` directory

Comment: Same problem with that and also need to update the `Dockerfile` for the image build

Comment: You need to fix your Dockerfile to add the application properly

Comment: I have problem understanding what the changes then need to be and why can't the changes be done for the Dockerfile in it's current location.

Comment: Also wondering why I see `can't open file '/src/main.py':` even when I change hte `CMD` part to use only `main.py` or `./src/main.py` - Something simple that I must be missing

Comment: I basically managed to solve this by using `docker compose build --no-cache`. Wasn't aware of Docker using so much caching